# How to draw a simple straight line?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I want to draw a straight line from point `x1, y2` to point `x2, y2`.

**I'm new to objective-c and I would like this to be as simple as possible.**

Performance is not an issue as the code will not run many times per second.

So far I've tried using a custom `UIView` and overriding `drawRect`:

```
@interface LineView : UIView
-(id) init;
-(void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect;
@end

@implementation LineView
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
    path.lineWidth = 3;
    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}
@end
```

**Usage:**

(I want everything added to `boardView`, so I add the line as a subview.)

```
LineView *myView = [[LineView alloc] init];
[boardView addSubview:myView];
```

Nothing new is displayed on the app. I inspected `boardView` and the `lineView` object is in its `subviews`. However it is completely blank:
[image]

Comment: The drawing code looks fine. The likely cause is that you neither gave LineView any dimension, nor a position within its superview.

Comment: If it's just simple horizontal line, then just add simple view

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your inspector I can see `frame = (0 0; 0 0);` this means that your view has zero width and height.

You should be able to see your graphics if you do something like:

```objectivec
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 110, 110);
    LineView* myView = [[LineView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [boardView addSubview:myView];
```

assuming that your board view has non-zero width and height.

The call `CGRect CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height);` creates a `CGRect` to use as the frame for your view. The `x`,`y` of the rectangle are used to position your view in the coordinate system of the parent and the `width` and `height` determine the size of your view.

Obviously, you will want to change the position to suit your needs.